# How to define cast and implicit cast operations for a Scala class of mine?

Tags: scala, casting, implicit, implicit-conversion

For example I'd like to have this to work the way to set `jDName` to "John Doe" and `jDAge` to 32:

```
case class Person(name : String, surname : String, age : Int)

val johnDoe = Person("John", "Doe", 32)

val jDName : String = johnDoe

val jDAge : Int = johnDoe
```

Can I write functions in the `Person` class to provide implicit conversion to String, Int and other (custom) types? And another thing is for explicit cast operation - also interesting, but I don't know exactly how should I write this for an example in Scala.

Comment: You can, but it's a really bad idea.  You have two different strings which are not distinguished by type.  If one gets converted implicitly and the other doesn't, that'd get awfully confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, put them in the companion object.

```
scala> case class Person(name : String, surname : String, age : Int); object Person {
     |   implicit def pToString(p: Person) = p.name + " " + p.surname + ", age " + p.age
     |   implicit def pToInt(p: Person) = p.age
     | }
defined class Person
defined module Person

scala> val johnDoe = Person("John", "Doe", 32)
johnDoe: Person = Person(John,Doe,32)

scala> val jDName : String = johnDoe
jDName: String = John Doe, age 32

scala> val jDAge : Int = johnDoe
jDAge: Int = 32
```

Comment: How would this advice look in the DI world without companion objects? So `case class Person` and `@Singleton case PersonService`?

Comment: @wwkudu Assuming by DI you mean dynamic dependency injection, it doesn't. Implicits are resolved statically, so nothing that happens at run time makes a difference.

Answer (score 9):

Would this work?

```
object Person {
  implicit def pToString(p: Person) = p.name + " " + p.surname + ", age " + p.age
  implicit def pToInt(p: Person) = p.age
}
import Person._
```

Comment: It'd probably work, but I was curious if it could be done in the class itself (as in C#, for example).

Comment: @Ivan you can't put them in the class itself, as nothing there can be "static", everything in a class is scoped to the instance. What you want is something in a more generic scope. In the example case above this is the companion object Person and therefore in scope when dealing with the instance class Person.

Comment: Sorry, Ivan, but why did you mark Daniel's response as the answer and not mine. They're exactly the same and mine was first. Oh well! =)